# rails respond_to pdf format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdftk

I'm following a tutorial to fill pdf and send to browser... but with error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/registries/customers_controller.rb:113:in `print_bollettino_2’

112  def print_bollettino_2
113    respond_to do |format|
114      format.pdf { send_file BollettinoUtente2Sezioni.new(@customer).export, type: 'application/pdf' }
115    end
116  end
```

Can you help me?

Many thanks,

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will put a `format.pdf` in the `respond_to`, you need to declare the new format to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` by adding:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

But you can also implement it directly as:

```
def print_bollettino_2
   send_file BollettinoUtente2Sezioni.new(@customer).export, type: 'application/pdf'
end
```

You can also use:

`send_data BollettinoUtente2Sezioni.new(@customer).export, type: 'application/pdf'`

if the function for generation of pdf does not return a filepath.